# Setting axis properties on axis-sharing plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Say I have a plot with several axis-sharing subplots, such as the one below. How can I control where the `x_ticks` go in the x-axis shared by all the subplots?

For example, say I want to display the ticks only on the following values of X: `0, 50 and 100`. As far as I understand, for the method `ax.set_xticks` I need to specify an axis, but they all share one, how do I get its handle?

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ix in xrange(3):
  ax = axes[ix]
  t = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
  s = np.sin(0.1*np.pi*t)*np.exp(-t*0.01)

  ax.plot(t,s)
```

Update:

How can I also have a `ylabel` for all my subplots that is centered vertically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `plt.setp`:

```
plt.setp(axes[-1], xticks=[5,10,45])
```

[image: shared x]

FYI, more information here:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html

Comment: Thanks! I updated the OP with this additional question: How can I render a centered `ylabel` that applies to all plots? (it may be long and span the height of multiple subplots)

Comment: Should work just to put it on the middle one: `plt.setp(axes[1], ylabel='hello this is a very long ylabel that spans several axes')`